# Where to download shapefiles of interest for Honduras

Tags: shapefile, data

Where can I download free Shapefile data for Honduras including:

- roads
- departments
- municipalities
- points of interest

Comment: have a look at open street map

Answer (score 3):

[DIVA GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/) will give you roads and municipalities (and I think departments).

[OSM](http://download.geofabrik.de/) will give you roads, municipalities and some POIs (and I think departments).

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) will give you municipalities and roads (and I think departments).

[GeoCommunity](http://www.geocomm.com/) will give you roads, municipalities and places (and I think departments).

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) will give you places.